# What would be the acceptable procedure (if any) for creating a Google Scholar page for someone else?

Tags: google-scholar, bibliometrics

When doing research to answer [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/121658/have-there-ever-been-any-lebron-james-of-academia) question, I would have loved to see the Google Scholar page of Nobel Laureate Martin Karplus. However it does not exist. There is a Google Scholar page for Richard Feynman, and for Albert Einstein and Sigmund Freud, most likely not created by themselves. Clearly it's possible to make a Google Scholar page for someone without a "verified email". **How does one do this?**

I understand that the examples I gave were not for living people, but I wonder if there is a way to make a page (**or to request a page**) for a living person, without using a fake email address.

I did search online before coming here, and the best I could find was the article "[Can I create a google scholar profile for someone else?](https://www.econjobrumors.com/topic/can-i-create-a-google-scholar-profile-for-someone-else)" and this did not satisfy me as being a complete search.

Answer (score 10):

The pages for Feynman, Einstein, and others (probably including Freud) were set up manually by the team behind Google Scholar back before the service launched in 2011, as evidenced by this [blog post](https://scholar.googleblog.com/2011/07/google-scholar-citations.html). Without their access, I believe you need to provide an (possibly fake) email address, as done for [Theodore Dru Alison Cockerell](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=5qvdHjQAAAAJ), see [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/61689/17254). I would, however, suggest you not to attempt creating a profile for any living person besides yourself (including Karplus) without their consent. Them not having a profile could, after all, be an active choice.